# Equality constraint between two type parameters

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following issue :

interface :

```
public interface IReader<TOut>
{
    IEnumerable<TOut> GetData(int from, int size);

    TOut Read<TKey>(TKey input);
}
```

then I have several implementations like this one :

```
    public class ConcreteReader<TOut> : IReader<TOut>
    {
        private IReader<TOut> parentReader;

        public IEnumerable<TOut> GetData(int from, int size)
        {
            // do stuff, don't need TKey for this
        }

        public TOut Read<TKey>(TKey Input)
        {
            this.parentReader.Read(input);
            ... // Do my job
            return result;
        }
    }
```

but one of them already knows TKey :

```
public class MultiReader<TKey, TOut> : IReader<TOut>
{
    public IEnumerable<TOut> GetData(int from, int size)
    {
        // do stuff. need TKey here
    }

    // this method does the job but it can't be the implementation of IReader<TOut>.Read<TKey>
    public TOut Read(TKey input)
    {
        ...
    }

    // this is the implementation of IReader<TOut>.Read<TKey>
    // I would like to enforce TKey == TKey1 but I can't write 
    // where TKey1 : TKey because the constraint would have to be on IReader interface
    public TOut Read<TKey1>(TKey1 input)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Based on another post I was able to write :

```
public TOut Read<TKey1>(TKey1 input)
{
    if (input is TKey)
    {
        object objectId = (object)input;
        TKey keyId = (TKey)objectId;
        return this.Read(keyId);
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

but I find it very ugly.

Any better option?
I hope this explanation is clear enough.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When the type system fights this hard against something I'm trying to do I usually take a step back and think things over because chances are that I'm doing something wrong. This is the scenario you are in. As others have pointed out, `IMultiReader` has no business implementing `IReader`. Both have very diferent contracts: The latter can read *any* input, the former can only read one concrete type of input. In what useful scenario would you be using a `IMultiReader` through an `IReader` interface? Interesting question by the way +1.

Comment: @InBetween There is a Strategy class that contains a chain of IReader. Basically when someone calls Strategy.Read, it passes the call to its IReader which in turn calls its parent and so on. TKey is not defined in IReader because most of implementations don't need to know it to do their job except for Read method (thus the type parameter on Read). However MultiReader does need to know TKey for everything it does and it wouldn't make sense to have a MultiReader without a TKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `IReader<TOut>` is contract, there is no way to hide that method. Interface requires exposing method that meets specified cotnract signature.  But.. you can do a little trick here with explicit interface implementation:

```
public class MultiReader<TKey, TOut> : IReader<TOut>
{
    public TOut Read(TKey input)
    {
        return ((IReader<TOut>)this).Read<TKey>(input);
    }

    TOut IReader<TOut>.Read<TKey1>(TKey1 input)
    {
         if (input is TKey)
        {
            object objectId = (object)input;
            TKey keyId = (TKey)objectId;
            return this.Read(keyId);
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var mr = new MultiReader<string, string>();
var test = mr.Read("someKey"); //OK
var test2 = mr.Read<int>(1); //compile-time error
```

But you can still do

```
var mr = new MultiReader<string, string>();
var test = mr.Read("someKey"); //OK
var test2 = ((IReader<string>)mr).Read<int>(1); //that is ok,
                                                //we use contract - we cannot prevent this
```

So that is why you still need cast-check in implementation.

Comment: In your example Read() calls into Read<TKey1>() which in turn calls into Read()...smells like StackOverflowException to me ;) But I got the idea. Still not perfect but much better than what I have. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't ever plan on using `MultiReader` as an `IReader` then why bother making it implement the `IReader` interface? The idea is that you'd be able to store the reference as an IReader and use the object interchangeably with any other type that implements `IReader`. That doesn't seem to be the case with `MultiReader`.

In my opinion, `MultiReader` should not implement `IReader` because it seems like you don't intend to use it via the `IReader` interface. Be wary of violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: actually I do need to use it as an IReader<TOut>. There is a Strategy class that contains a chain of IReader<TOut> (each IReader has a parent and calls its Read method before calling its own). I just edited the code to reflect this.